# How to draw route in bing map from json response of snap to road api of bing

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

Bing snap to road api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/snap-points-to-roads

How to project the response on bing map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the points array into an array of Location objects and then pass that into a polyline to render it on the map as line. For example:

```
var coords = [];

response.points.forEach(p => {
    coords.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(p.latitude, p.longitude));
});

//Create a polyline
var line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(coords, {
    strokeColor: 'red'
});

//Add the polyline to map
map.entities.push(line);
```

Comment: Thank you very much